# Is there a Plone package to serve images via CDN (Amazon cloudfront)

Tags: amazon-s3, plone, amazon-cloudfront

Is there a way to manage images uploaded into a plone system, but have them be synced and automatically served with Amazon S3/Cloudfront?

I've seen reference to a project that doesn't look like it's been touched since early 2011:  http://plone.org/products/collective.cdn.core/  and that only has experimental image support, and not necessarily for Amazon s3/cloudfront

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not yet an add-on product that makes this "point-and-click" easy.  https://github.com/collective/collective.cdn.core suggest that collective.cdn.core has continued to be developed, although the authors haven't pushed their releases to plone.org (shame shame!).  It still does not appear to include "native" Amazon/CloudFront support, but I suspect the add-on authors would welcome either code contributions or sponsorship to add that end.